# strip all comments from helm package

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, comments, kubernetes-helm, stripping

I have a lot of comments in my helm chart in my repository.
I want to deliver my helm chart to others without these comments.

I am hoping to be able to do this during my CI pipeline. I have a step in my pipeline which performs the `helm package` command. I am hoping to have this package completely stripped of comments (in the templates, values, etc)

I have not found a way to do this directly with helm.

Is there a simple solution to my problem?

I have already considered some ways to solve it but I feel like I am missing a simple solution here.
I know I can parse the values files and re write them using something like `yq` which will strip all comments. But that won't work for the template files as they are not valid yaml with the helm/go templating in them.

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: You'd have to build a tool that could parse the Go template syntax, explicitly remove the `{{/* ... */}}` comments (possibly with `-` whitespace control markers), and write it out again.  That feels complex to me.  Do you also need to remove comments in places like `NOTES.txt` or individual values that will be interpreted using `tpl`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - moved to devops https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17328/8189